# Load video from file with Kinect for Windows with SDK v2.0

Tags: c#, file, sdk, visual-studio-2013, kinect

I would load video from file, for example file registered with kinect studio v2, and track body with SDK v2.0.
i managed only from kinect sensor and not from file, how i can use file (.xef for example)?
I use visual studio and c#
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have resolved with kinect studio v2.0 or with serialization of Body in c# code.

Comment: Hi, would you please share how you do that? or where can I find the resources? Thanks

Comment: do you would like know how to serialize the body?

Comment: Yes, but I am more interested in how to load a .xef file and get the data

Comment: i have worked on my bodies registration. In one application i have serialized all frame with bodies and from another application i have deserialized all file. I don't worked with xef because recordings are of poor quality (lag, loss frame and kinect studio has more bug). So i have developed my application to record bodies and color frames.

Comment: Can you please provide some code snippet to show how did you read video from the file?

Comment: how I wrote above, I used serialization to write useful information on file for then read it. So I record only information that I need without memory waste and improving performance (record and read xef vdeo is too wasteful to my aim, otherwise I was supposed to record the video and elaborate it then when I load, now I store all information I would get in post processing)

Comment: I don't find the article that I used how base for my code, but you can read this to start http://www.academia.edu/3064906/Motion_Comparison_Using_Microsoft_Kinect